# JSON Decoding a Date in Swift

Tags: swift

I am facing a weird problem. I can run a code just fine in popular online Swift compilers, but in Xcode and in my iOS app, the results produced are wrong!

```
import Foundation

extension DateFormatter {
    static let iso8601Full: DateFormatter = {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
        return formatter
    }()
}

struct MyObj: Decodable {
    var endTime: Date?
}

let jsonString = "{\"endTime\":\"2021-02-20T18:29:59.999Z\"}"
let jsonData: Data? = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601Full)
let obj = try decoder.decode(MyObj.self, from: jsonData!)
print(obj)
```

The above code produces the expected output (as below) on online Swift compilers, such as online.swiftplayground.run, tutorialspoint.com, jdoodle.com

```
MyObj(endTime: Optional(2021-02-20 18:29:59 +0000))
```

But when the same code executes in Xcode on iOS emulator, the output produced is this:

```
MyObj(endTime: nil)
```

This is the exact code from my iOS app:

```
import Foundation

class RestClient {
  static let instance = RestClient()

  func get() {
      do {
        let jsonString = "{\"endTime\":\"2021-02-20T18:29:59.999Z\"}"
        let jsonData: Data? = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601Full)
        let obj = try decoder.decode(MyObj.self, from: jsonData!)
      } catch let error {
        print("JSON parsing error: \(error)")
      }
  }

  func jsonDecoder() -> JSONDecoder {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .formatted(DateFormatter.iso8601Full)
    return decoder
  }
}

extension DateFormatter {
  static let iso8601Full: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'"
    return formatter
  }()
}

struct MyObj: Decodable {
  var endTime: Date?
}
```

Can anyone please help me? I have verified that the Swift version is 5 for both Xcode and the online compilers.

Comment: Its printing fine for me `MyObj(endTime: Optional(2021-02-20 12:59:59 +0000))`

Comment: What locale is your iOS simulator?

Comment: Remove the single quotes around the `Z`. The character represents the time zone.

Comment: Your code should execute. I am just weirded out by your get function not returning anything. :)

Comment: as already mentioned by vadian you should NOT escape the Z. If you escape it will ignore the timezone when parsing the date string. `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"` and make sure to set your locale to "en_US_POSIX" before setting the dateFormat

Comment: @SandeepBhandari that result is wrong. It should print "2021-02-20 18:29:59 +0000". The date formatter is ignoring the UTC timezone present on the string "Z" and it is interpreting it as current timezone which is wrong.